# Hide sub domain created for local CDN

Tags: subdomains

Not sure if my question would make sense or not. I have created a sub-domain to store some of my static files (like images). So, some images now load from **http://imgs.example.com/imagefilename.png**

Now, the problem is, all the files stored under this sub domain http://imgs.example.com/ are publicly visible which I want to hide or redirect or show 404. Any idea how to achieve this?

Currently files in the subdomain shows --

**Index of /**

- cgi-bin/
- onevideofile.mp4
- oneimagefile.png

*Apache Server at imgs.iconicwebteam.com Port 80*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go around and not allow indexes?

Add this to a .htaccess file, in the same directory as the .png and .mp4 files.

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: thanks man. it worked like a charm. Now the directory is showing 403 errors.. :)

Comment: Or put an empty index.php in that directory, or with modified headers to show 404?

Comment: hmm. not a bad idea though.. which one will better.. working with htaccess file or putting a blank index file @frederik spang

Comment: They'll do essentially the same - Index shows 404, and .htaccess will give a 403. Either way, the directory index will be gone.